# how to remove multiple login saved from chrome

Tags: google-chrome, login

I am using Chrome browser Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)
but due to using many gmail accounts I have saved it.
The problem is when I am with some friend or some one
and multiple accounts show in text box when I have
to enter username. I want to delete multiple usernames saved in Chrome,
meaning the information be saved but I don't want it to appear as drop down.
I cleared cookies, cache, filled form information but nothing worked.
What should I do

Answer (score 1):

Open a Chrome window.
Click on the three dots in the upper right corner. Choose your settings.
Choose a password. ...
To delete a single password, click on the three dots next to the password and select "Delete".
To remove all passwords, go to "Clear browsing data from settings -> Advanced" and select "Passwords".

Comment: I have done this but saved login information is not getting deleted.